# standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" Docker with go basic web app

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

The very basic web app is created in Go

```
package main

import(
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func hostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    name, err :=os.Hostname()

    if err != nil {
           panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>HOSTNAME: %s</h1><br>",name)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>ENVIRONMENT VARS: </h1><br>")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<ul>")

        for _, evar := range os.Environ(){
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "<li>%s</li>",evar)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "</ul>")

}

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Awesome site in Go!</h1><br>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<a href='/host/'>Host info</a><br>")

}

func main() {

        http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/host/", hostHandler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)


}
```

Docker File for it

```
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/go
COPY webapp /
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/webapp"]
```

The image is built successfully

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-125:~/go/src/hello$ docker build -t "webapp" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.152MB
Step 1/5 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/go
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8810a06c58c7
Step 3/5 : COPY webapp /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d75222363d3a
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 45de0853de8e
Step 5/5 : CMD ["/webapp"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9f9031f3632
Successfully built e9f9031f3632
Successfully tagged webapp:latest
```

But when i run the docker its show error.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/go/src/hello$ docker run webapp
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Please guide what is the issue, I am new to docker and go.

Environment-related information

```
ubuntu@ip:~/go/src/hello$ ls
Dockerfile  webapp
ubuntu@ip:~/go/src/hello$ echo $GOPATH
/home/ubuntu/go
```

Code was compiled with **go build webapp.go** command

Comment: Please include your compile command.

Comment: BMitch code was compiled with go build webapp.go command

Answer (score 21, accepted):

File not found can mean the file is missing, a script missing the interpreter, or an executable missing a library. In this case, the net import brings in libc by default, as a dynamic linked binary. You should be able to see that with `ldd` on your binary.

To fix it, you'll need to pass some extra flags:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w' -o mybin *.go
```

The above is from: https://medium.com/@diogok/on-golang-static-binaries-cross-compiling-and-plugins-1aed33499671

Answer (score 9):

In my case `CGO_ENABLED=0` was the key to fix this problem.

**Cgo** allows to use inline C code in Go sources, see more: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

I reckon by default Cgo links your application dynamically to **libc**, even if you don't use any inline C.
And libc is missing when you package your application to Docker image `FROM scratch`

Here is my working **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install


FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app"]
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you might need `CGO_ENABLED` because of a dependency like `mattn/go-sqlite3`, you can pass static compilation down the chain using this:

```
RUN go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"'
```

- `go build` tells `go link` (`-ldflags`)
- to tell the external linker (`-extldflags`) `clang` or `gcc`
- to link it's libraries statically, i.e. not in separate files

Then when the executable is run, it won't try to load an external library like `libc.so`, or `libpthread.so` and be unable to find the file "no such file or directory" as soon as it loads.

## Before

```
RUN go build -o myapp
```

```
$ ldd myapp
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7ff635fb9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7ff635fb9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7ff635fb9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7ff635fb9000)
```

## After

```
RUN go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o myapp
```

```
$ ldd myapp
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: /usr/bin/walnutcube-api: Not a valid dynamic program
```

That is good, we don't want it to be a "dynamic program" we want it to be one of the only files on the system in a scratch container.

Answer (score 3):

build:

```sh
# build
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o myapp main.go
```

dockerfile:

```
#FROM alpine:3.10
FROM scratch
COPY . /

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/myapp", "-c", "app.ini"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change line in your Dockerfile

`COPY webapp /webapp`

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it works

```
env GOARCH=386 GOOS=linux go build webapp.go
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case en env was not enough:
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64

I had to add as well in the build the tags and ldflags:
RUN go build -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w' -o /go/bin/myService *.go