# Docker - can't exec copied executable file

Tags: linux, docker, go

I have a docker file in my src directory of Go project. I prebuilt executable by running `GOOS=linux go build -o main cmd/*.go`
Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY main .
COPY configs/. .
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["/main"]
```

Docker builds it without any error,but when trying to start container with `docker run -p 8081:8081 -it myService` I got:
`exec /main: no such file or directory`

I inspected container files by `docker export` and main executable is in root folder, but docker says there's no such file or directory. I've tried changing `/main` to `.main` but it doesn't help.

Comment: You could try `[ "./main" ]` as `CMD`. What are the permissions of the executable? What do you see when you start the container with `--entrypoint /bin/sh` and run `ls -lisa`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note: You can probably copy a program from /bin or so, no need to compile anything yourself, so you can also resolve the relation to go from the tags.

Comment: `3287876  15232 -rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root      15596040 Mar 23 17:25 main`
 i see main file, but i can't execute it. Also ./main not worked

Comment: You probably have a different version of libc in the docker image than on the host. Try building with CGO_ENABLED=0.

Comment: I recompiled binary with `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o [name of binary]` parameters and it is working now.

Comment: The Alpine base image has a different system C library and that can occasionally cause problems like this.  [How to run a docker container created with go binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168513/how-to-run-a-docker-container-created-with-go-binary) seems to be a similar setup and also suggests `CGO_ENABLED=0`; does that question describe your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is not necessary `/` directory.

So you should use `CMD ["./main"]` instead of `CMD ["/main"]` or `COPY main /main` instead of `COPY main .`.

An important point: you should compile your binary file inside your Dockerfile instead of copying this one. If you just copy binary, it will depend of the initial environment where you compile it and may not be compatible with the os used in your Dockerfile.

Try something like that:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /main

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/main" ]
```

Comment: The working directory on `alpine:latest` is the root directory though.