# Docker standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, go, kubernetes, containers

Whenever I am trying to run the docker images, it is exiting in immediately.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
ae327a2bdba3   k8s-for-beginners:v0.0.1   "/k8s-for-beginners"   11 seconds ago   Exited (1) 10 seconds ago             focused_booth
```

As per Container Logs

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

I have created all the files in linux itself:

```
FROM alpine:3.10
COPY k8s-for-beginners /
CMD ["/k8s-for-beginners"]
```

GO Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("Ping from %s", r.RemoteAddr)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello Kubernetes Beginners!")
}
```

This is the first exercise from THE KUBERNETES WORKSHOP book.

Commands I have used in this Process:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o k8s-for-beginners
sudo docker build -t k8s-for-beginners:v0.0.1 .
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -d k8s-for-beginners:v0.0.1
```

Output of the command:

```bash
sudo docker run k8s-for-beginners:v0.0.1 ldd /k8s-for-beginners
```

```
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9ab5778000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9ab5778000)
Error loading shared library libgo.so.16: No such file or directory (needed by /k8s-for-beginners)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /k8s-for-beginners)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /k8s-for-beginners)
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2frsa..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fx509..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: log..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fmd5..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: bytes..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: fmt.Fprintln: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2felliptic..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fx509..z2fpkix..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2frand..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fchacha20poly1305..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fcurve25519..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fidna..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2foserror..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fecdsa..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp.HandleFunc: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: io..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp2..z2fhpack..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fcipher..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: log.Fatal: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..z2fbig..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: hash..z2fcrc32..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp.ListenAndServe: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: context..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: fmt..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2ftls..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: errors..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2ftestlog..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.setIsCgo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_m: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fhex..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2funicode..z2fbidi..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2freflectlite..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: compress..z2fgzip..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: sync..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: compress..z2fflate..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fbinary..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..z2frand..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_cpuinit: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fpoll..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..z2fmultipart..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.check: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fcryptobyte..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha512..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.registerTypeDescriptors: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fchacha20..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.setmodinfo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2ftransform..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: time..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fbase64..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha256..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: __go_go: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp..z2fhttpguts..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: path..z2ffilepath..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2fsecure..z2fbidirule..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: os..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp..z2fhttpproxy..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2ftextproto..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fasn1..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.requireitab: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fdns..z2fdnsmessage..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: path..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: io..z2fioutil..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: sort..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2funicode..z2fnorm..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fcpu..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.ginit: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.osinit: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.schedinit: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: bufio..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2finternal..z2frandutil..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_mstart: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: strconv..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.args: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..z2finternal..z2fsys..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.newobject: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: syscall..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: unicode..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp..z2finternal..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fpem..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: _Unwind_Resume: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..z2fquotedprintable..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: log.Printf: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.typedmemmove: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fdsa..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha1..import: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: bufio..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: bytes..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: compress..z2fflate..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: compress..z2fgzip..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: context..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fcipher..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fdsa..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fecdsa..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2felliptic..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2finternal..z2frandutil..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fmd5..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2frand..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2frsa..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha1..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha256..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsha512..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2ftls..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fx509..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fx509..z2fpkix..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fasn1..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fbase64..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fbinary..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fhex..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: encoding..z2fpem..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: errors..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: fmt..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fchacha20..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fchacha20poly1305..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fcryptobyte..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fcurve25519..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fdns..z2fdnsmessage..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp..z2fhttpguts..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp..z2fhttpproxy..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fhttp2..z2fhpack..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fnet..z2fidna..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2fsecure..z2fbidirule..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2ftransform..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2funicode..z2fbidi..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2ftext..z2funicode..z2fnorm..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: hash..z2fcrc32..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fcpu..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2foserror..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fpoll..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2freflectlite..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2ftestlog..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: io..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: io..z2fioutil..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: log..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..z2fbig..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..z2frand..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..z2fmultipart..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: mime..z2fquotedprintable..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp..z2finternal..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2ftextproto..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: os..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: path..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: path..z2ffilepath..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..z2finternal..z2fsys..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: sort..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: strconv..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: sync..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: syscall..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: time..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: unicode..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: container..z2flist..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2faes..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fdes..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fed25519..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fed25519..z2finternal..z2fedwards25519..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fhmac..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2finternal..z2fsubtle..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2frc4..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: crypto..z2fsubtle..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fcryptobyte..z2fasn1..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fhkdf..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2finternal..z2fsubtle..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: golang.x2eorg..z2fx..z2fcrypto..z2fpoly1305..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: hash..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fbytealg..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2ffmtsort..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fnettrace..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2frace..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fsingleflight..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fsyscall..z2fexecenv..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: internal..z2fsyscall..z2funix..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: math..z2fbits..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2fhttp..z2fhttptrace..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net..z2furl..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..z2finternal..z2fatomic..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime..z2finternal..z2fmath..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: strings..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: sync..z2fatomic..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: unicode..z2futf16..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: unicode..z2futf8..types: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.strequal..f: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.memequal64..f: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: type...1reflect.rtype: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Align: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Align: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.AssignableTo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.AssignableTo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Bits: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Bits: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.ChanDir: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.ChanDir: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Comparable: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Comparable: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.ConvertibleTo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.ConvertibleTo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Elem: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Elem: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Field: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Field: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldAlign: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldAlign: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByIndex: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByIndex: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByName: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByName: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByNameFunc: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.FieldByNameFunc: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Implements: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Implements: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.In: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.In: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.IsVariadic: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.IsVariadic: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Key: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Key: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Kind: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Kind: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Len: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Len: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Method: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Method: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.MethodByName: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.MethodByName: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Name: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Name: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumField: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumField: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumIn: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumIn: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumMethod: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumMethod: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumOut: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.NumOut: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Out: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Out: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.PkgPath: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.PkgPath: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Size: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.Size: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.String: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.String: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.common: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.common: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.rawString: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.rawString: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.uncommon..stub: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect.rtype.uncommon..stub: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: reflect..reflect.rtype..d: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: type...1net.IPAddr: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.Network: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.Network: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.String: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.String: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.family: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.family: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.isWildcard: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.isWildcard: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.sockaddr: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.sockaddr: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.toLocal: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr.toLocal: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: net.IPAddr..d: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.main: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_iscgo: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_isstarted: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime_isarchive: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: __gcc_personality_v0: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: io.Writer..d: symbol not found
Error relocating /k8s-for-beginners: runtime.writeBarrier: symbol not found
```

Comment: having done exactly as you described + adding a go.mod file the docker image is up and running and I can see the output by accessing localhost:8080.

Comment: Your setup looks good & should work. I would suggest removing `sudo` - as it is not necessary and actually a security risk.

Comment: Without SUDO i am not able to run docker at all. Its not Production, just running on my laptop

Comment: @meaningqo - In my case i don't have go.mod even not as per instructions from the book.

Comment: @Ramesh from a laptop you can (and should) run docker as non-root: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Comment: The error looks like the binary was compiled without disabling cgo (despite the steps listed). Please include the output from `sudo docker run k8s-for-beginners:v0.0.1 ldd /k8s-for-beginners`

Comment: @BMitch  I have added the Output in my question

Comment: libc being linked when you include networking in go is normal, and will cause this error when you run in Alpine since it doesn't have libc (instead it uses musl). The fix is to disable cgo. Double check you have run the commands exactly as you've shown in your question.

Comment: @BMitch Yes i have ran the same commands. But no luck. I have doubt on go.mod which is not mentioned in book instructions also.

Comment: if your go build creates the binary, then it should not be the go.mod issue. i just added it, because without it it wouldn't compile for me.

Comment: This is a common error, and the solution is to get ldd to state it is not a dynamically linked library. CGO is a common cause because networking pulls in libc, but there are other possible causes (none of which I see in the go code you've shared). For similar issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55106186/596285, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52640304/596285, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56168513/596285.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using `Docker`, I'd suggest using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Using a standard docker image like `golang` one can build an executable asset which is guaranteed to work with other docker linux images:

```
FROM golang:1.17 as builder

# first (build) stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o k8s-for-beginners

# final (target) stage

FROM alpine:3.10
COPY --from=builder /app/k8s-for-beginners /
CMD ["/k8s-for-beginners"]
```

Note: you since you are using `CGO_ENABLED=0` you can run your app in a much smaller `scratch` container. To do so replace `FROM alpine:3.10` with `FROM scratch`

---

P.S. ensure you have a `go.mod` file in the same directory as the `Go` source and `Dockerfile`:

```
go mod init k8sapp     # creates a `go.mod`
```

or you can create `go.mod` manually:

```
module k8sapp

go 1.17
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Not sure why the different instructions are there in the The Kubernetes Workshop Book

Comment: Your original questions as posed "should" work. I've crossed compiled on a Mac - for `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64` without issue. As @BMitch noted, double check your build script. Ensure each step does error checking before proceeding to the next step. Running the last steps with `sudo` may be picking up the wrong binary during user-context switch...

Answer (score 19):

In my particular case, this exact error was caused by a Bash entry script with incorrect Windows/DOS line endings.

Add this to the Docker file:

```
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh
```

If `dos2unix` is not installed, prefix with:

```
# For Alpine Linux:
RUN apk add dos2unix
# For Ubuntu:
RUN apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: upvoted because this lead me to the right answer. it was the CRLF in the file; however, I would highly recommend that if you have the problem you just use your IDE to change the file line endings and rebuild the container instead of adding in extraneous programs to your container.

Comment: @SemicolonsandDuctTape Thank you for the upvote. However, given that dos2unix is tiny, I believe it is worth the tradeoff to create a container that is less brittle. This ties in with the Robustness Principle (in particular, the second part): `Be conservative in what you send; be liberal in what you accept.`. Most containers have dos2unix by default, so there is no cost.

Answer (score 5):

check your startup.sh file ending character `LF` not `CRLF`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwF4q.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! This happens sometimes, when you create a file through Windows Explorer on a WSL2 distro's disk.

Answer (score 2):

The error `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory` can be caused by having the dynamic linker in the wrong location or not present.

For example, compile a simple "hello world" test.cpp:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ test.cpp
```

Check where the executable expects the dynamic linker to be:

```
$ readelf -l a.out | grep -i interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Now here is where a possible error can occur: you want to create a minimal container image from scratch, so you copy all the libraries from `ldd a.out` to a filesystem, maybe using a command like [this](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10238/copy-all-shared-libraries-for-a-binary-to-directory)

```
$ ldd a.out | grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' cp -v '{}' image_root/lib64
$ ldd a.out | grep '^\s*/' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' cp -v '{}' image_root/lib64
$ cp a.out image_root/bin/a.out
$ tar -C image_root -cvjSf image_root.tar.bz2 bin lib64
```

Finally, using a containerfile/dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD image_root.tar.bz2 /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/a.out"]
```

```
$ podman build -t test -f Containerfile .
$ podman run --rm test
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

The solution to this problem is to ensure that the dynamic linker is placed in the correct location on the filesystem, so in this case `cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 image_root/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` when creating the filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

when build image, I use arm64v8/busybox:latest, then it's ok

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).